# how to use a common validation for all input fields in a page?

Tags: php, html, validation, input

i have 61 fields in a page, i need input validation , if any one leaves a field blank and enter submit then a error message should show. because i can`t code for every single field validation, quite lengthy. numeric field should accept only numbers, here the field is "phn_no". i am just showing only 2 fields. thank you folks.

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" name="phn_no" id="phn_no">
<input type="submit" value="save" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: foreach loop on $_POST looking for empty fields?

Comment: use `required` attribute

Comment: please, help me by giving proper code.

Comment: So, You didn't even attempt to try ?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
<input type="number" name="phn_no" id="phn_no" required>` try this lets see a magic

Comment: *requried* you mean `required` @Sathish ;-)

Comment: yes @fred-ii sorry for that typo mistake

Comment: @Dagon feel like filling out 61 fields? copy/paste does magic too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i hate this time of day on s.o

Comment: @Dagon it'll be breakfast in about 5 hours for me. But yeah, I know what you mean; and nobody listened to us. Server-side's the best.

Answer (score 1):

Use input like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
```

required field must be fill then only we submit the form otherwise it display notification.

Comment: that's already been established in comments and is only valid with HTML5 and isn't supported by Safari. A server-side method is by far, a much better method.

Comment: thanks friend.. it worked. i am using fiorefox. it works on it.

Comment: I still think a server-side method would be best @PriyaMajumder as stated in my comment just above, if you haven't read that. Now you have to edit 61 fields to enter the word "required" in it. While my way, you wouldn't. Oh well, to each their own ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii-  in server-side validation check any empty $_POST value is submitted. If yes redirect to form page. It will work for all browsers.

Comment: @Fred -ii- how to do that ,, can you provide me some sample code